# Couldn't run individual scala test in Intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I came across an issue earlier where I couldn't run an indivdual scala test, it would always try to run all of them even if I set the configuration to just be running one test. Does anyone know of any settings/configuration I can change to get it to run?

```
class MyTest extends PlaySpec {
    val setTo = new AfterWord("set to")

    "Setting" when setTo {
        "value a" in {
            //test stuff
        }

        "value b" in {
            //test stuff
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was the use of the AfterWord that was messing up my test, once I removed it the tests ran fine. I'm not sure why they're incompatible but if you want to run individual tests, don't use an AfterWord.